# JQuery number format from input

Tags: jquery, numbers

Sill Q I know - sorry in advance - but how do you read a decimal point value in JQuery. e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="1.23">
```

Then take that value "1.23" into something like this

```
var test   = $(this).val();
$(this).next('.txt').text(test);
```

Where .txt is the "next" div with a class of txt and "$(this)" is the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
   <input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="1.23">
    <div class='txt'></div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#test').next('.txt').text($('#test').val());
```

Demo is [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/KdqJm/).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but you can read a value using `.val()` function in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. It looks okay to me. It could be shortened down to this:

```
$(this).next('.txt').text($(this).val())
```